# Asignar una función a una variable

Tags: ruby

Bueno tengo un objeto `questions` que como pueden ver recibe parámetros true/false, lo que quisiera es que en a la variable `question_type`  dado el valor de `questions[:q1]`  se le asigne una de las funciones `question_type_true` o `question_type_false` para poder ejecutarlo en dentro del each.

> el valor de q1 es el permite saber a cuál función van en question_type

```
questions = {
  q1: true,
  q3: true,
  q4: true,
  q5: true,
  q6: true,
  q7: true,
  q8: true
}

question_type = questions[:q1] == true ? question_type_true : question_type_false

questions.each do |key, value|
  question_type(value)
end


def question_type_true(question)
  p "true #{question}"
end

def question_type_false(question)
  p "false #{question}"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método que buscas es [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-send), el cual te permite ejecutar un método utilizando un *string* o *symbol*; en tu ejemplo:

```
questions = {
  q1: true,
  q3: true,
  q4: true,
  q5: true,
  q6: true,
  q7: true,
  q8: true
}

def question_type_true(question)
  p "true #{question}"
end

def question_type_false(question)
  p "false #{question}"
end

# No es necesario utilizar `questions[:q1] == true`, ya que sería lo mismo que poner
# `true == true`; por lo tanto la expresión puede reducirse a `questions[:q1]`.
question_type = questions[:q1] ? "question_type_true" : "question_type_false"

questions.each do |_, value|
  send(question_type, value)
end
```

El primer argumento es el nombre del método, el cual se arma dinámicamente (con un string) y el segundo es el argumento del método que estás invocando.

Salida:

```
"true true"
"true true"
"true true"
"true true"
"true true"
"true true"
"true true"
#=> {:q1=>true, :q3=>true, :q4=>true, :q5=>true, :q6=>true, :q7=>true, :q8=>true}
```

Comment: Hola Gerry  gracias por responder, pero no es lo que quiero si puedes ver en la variable `question_type`  es donde quisiera asignar la función y llamarla puesto que dependiendo del valor del q1 deberían de entrar a una u otra función.

Comment: @mariovzc Ya veo, claro, depende de `q1`; actualicé la respuesta para que utilice exactamente tu mismo código pero con `send`.

Comment: Gerry te comento que eso era lo que faltaba muchas gracias !